In Islam, is the nature of God imprinted on the soul?
I guess its a philosophical question, or perhaps maybe one that can't be answered.
But, in any case, is there any evidence in Islam that the true nature of God is imprinted on the soul?  That is, is it innately part of human nature to understand it without revelation.
For example, Allah says "My Mercy encompasses all things".  Or, other general concepts that Allah is perfect in all of His attributes of Justice, Wisdom, etc.

Look into "fitrah".

Thanks @UmH  the reason I ask is scholars differed on the nature of God.  But, even with those differences truth can only be one.  So I wonder if there is this knowledge innate, but for reasons beyond us we still have differences in opinion.

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and the SE model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].
